# How to manually trigger the click event in actionscript/flex3?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex3

Similar to the below in javascript:

```
<input id="target" type="button" onclick="..." />

<script>
document.getElementById('target').click();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use dispatchEvent function :
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=events_07.html

You should create a new instance of the click event event before firing

Comment: thanks for your comment,but sorry I now have some modification to the problem,that is: how can I manually dispatch the click event when the status of button switches to enabled for the **first time**?

Comment: 1)For this you have to write some code to track the first time of the button becoming enabled. 2)When you say enabled you mean when the mouse moves over it ? If yes, then subscribe to the mouseover event and write the code to check the first time & fire the event if 3) you are referring to the enabled property of the button control you have to write that code wherever you are enabling it & fire the event

Answer (score 0):

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class ClickEventExample
    {
        public static function dispatchClickEventFrom(something:DisplayObject):void
        {
            something.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what is the point of this? i would recommend using a custom event in this case, so you do not confuse yourself with `MouseEvent.CLICK` not representing a click at all.

if, like ivo suggests, you want to fire an event when the user first rolls over your clip, this should get you started:

```
myClip.addEventListener( MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, handleFirstMouseOver );

function handleFirstMouseOver( e:MouseEvent ) : void
{
    dispatchEvent( new Event('mySpecialEvent', true ) );
    myClip.removeEventListener( MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, handleMouseOver );
}
```

If (and I am not assuming you are :) ) you are trying to fake a CLICK to get around pop-up blockers or enter FullScreen mode or something, then think again, because the player will recognize such events as not actually spawned from user input.